# Looking for an maven sample project for java persistence api with sqlite3

Tags: java, maven, jpa, sqlite

I am new to maven and java persistence api 2.0 (to configuring it). I need to set up a project which uses maven for build, java persistent api 2.0 and sqlite3 as database backend.

What I am looking for is a maven sample project. 
I found one for objectdb :
 http://www.objectdb.com/tutorial/jpa/start/maven

something similar for sqlite3 would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked at the example of objectdb. But if you use jpa then you haven't much to do to change the underlying database. If you use a `resource` within a webapp, then you just have to set the server side configuration (e.g. `context.xml` in tomcat) to the new db. For Sqlite the text would be something like this:

```
<Resource Name="jdbc/<yourdatasource>" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="org.sqlite.JDBC" URL="jdbc:sqlite:<file>"
    maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" />
```

And don't forget to place the sqlite-driver-jar within the libraries folder of the server.

**Appendix:**

If you're writing a simple Java Project you have to set the following dependency within your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, but no web app. I want to write a command line application.

Comment: I added the maven dependency in the answer post.

Comment: You can look at http://codelook.com/2014/03/introduction-jpa/ what to do within the code as there's the one line `EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpa-test");` which differs from the objectdb example and the needed persistence.xml within the META-INF folder. (see the linked article)